# I have array with multiple images path and i want to print images using loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I have array with multiple images path and I want to print the images on my HTML page.

```
    function img() {
    var images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.png"];

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("modal-img").innerHTML = images[i].src;
    }
}

img();
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <img class="modal-content" id="modal-img">
</div>
```

Comment: what do mean by you wanna print the image, using printer or just display in the screen ?

Comment: I think you are missing the base path as well

Comment: I just want to display in the browser in simple way

Comment: Try to use react

Comment: ```document.querySelectorAll('.modal-img').forEach((x,i)=> x.src===images[i])```

Comment: I have to do it with for loop. I just have to display it in simple way.

Comment: Please view my updated answer, if it helped you make sure to upvote and accept as an answer :) @WaqasUmer

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to simplify this problem. What you want to end up with is x amount of img elements with a custom src attached to them.
Now, in order to achieve that, you will need to create the elements with js.

Let's start with the basic code to achieve that:

HTML (We don't need the img element anymore as we will create it with JS):

```html
<div id="modal" class="modal">
</div>
```

JS:

```js
function showImages() {
    const images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.png"];
    const modalElement = document.getElementById('modal');
 
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
        imageElement.classList.add('modal-content');
        modalElement.appendChild(imageElement);
    }
}
 
showImages();
```

We will now end up with 4 img elements with the .modal-content class.
What we have left to do is to add the src to the element which can be done by simply adding this line to the loop:

```js
imageElement.src = images[i];
```

Final Code:

HTML:

```html
<div id="modal" class="modal">
</div>
```

JS:

```js
function showImages() {
    const images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.png"];
    const modalElement = document.getElementById('modal');
 
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
        imageElement.classList.add('modal-content');
        imageElement.src = images[i];
        modalElement.appendChild(imageElement);
    }
}
 
showImages();
```

Comment: I have to use for loop

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the innerHTML of the image tag not setting it source. The code below should work.

`document.getElementById("modal-img").src = images[i];`

Comment: I did same but it is not showing any image in my browser nor any error in console.

Comment: function img() {
    var images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.png"];
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("modal-img").src = images[i]; 
    }
}

img();

Comment: The base path... `PATH_TO_IMAGE/${images[i]}`;

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense to insert the an array of paths into one image and using an id attribute for that.

I think you want more image nodes in your DOM and then insert those paths into those images

For instance

JS

```
const images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.png"];

document.querySelectorAll('.modal-img')
  .forEach((x, i) => {
    x.setAttribute('src', images[i])
  })
```

Using for loop:

```
const objArray = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-img')

for (let i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
  objArray[i].setAttribute('src', images[i])
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
  <img class=".modal-img">
  <img class=".modal-img">
  <img class=".modal-img">
</div>
```

Comment: I have to use for loop not foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly. This code will add all photos from array in the DIV with ID "modal". I hope I have been helpful.

HTML:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
</div>
```

JS: Add the JS code at the bottom of the HTML!

```
function img() {
    var images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.png"];
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML += '<img class="modal-content" id="modal-img" src="'+ images[i] +'">';
    }
}
img();
```

Comment: The images are in my root folder